# Jenkins - Groovy pipeline - Using FilePath gives Could not find matching constructor

Tags: jenkins, groovy

Building on this suggestion:
[Using FilePath to access workspace on slave in Jenkins pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41250567/using-filepath-to-access-workspace-on-slave-in-jenkins-pipeline)  I am trying to get the files that are dropped into the workspace by git, and iterate through those files using eachFileRecurse, by passing in the adjusted folder.  However, when calling into FilePath, I get errors.

```
    import groovy.io.FileType
    import java.io.File
    import java.lang.Object
    import hudson.FilePath
    import jenkins.model.Jenkins

    def createFilePath(path) {
    return new FilePath(Jenkins.getInstance().getComputer(env['NODE_NAME']).getChannel(), path);
    }

@NonCPS // has to be NonCPS or the build breaks on the call to .each
def getFiles(dirLoc) {
    def dir = new File (dirLoc)
    def list = []
    dir.eachFileRecurse (FileType.FILES)
            {file -> if (file.name.endsWith('.txt')) {list << file}}
    return list
}
```

I get this error

```
groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Could not find matching constructor for: java.io.File(hudson.FilePath)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeConstructor(MetaClassImpl.java:1737)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeConstructor(MetaClassImpl.java:1537)
```

I cannot figure out what I am missing here to make this work.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

There is no Constructor for java.io.file with hudson.FilePath as a parameter.

Refer to java doc at following link: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html