# Jenkins (linux) and EnvInject on node (Windows) file access

Tags: linux, windows, jenkins, groovy

I have installed Jenkins on a Linux host, and added a Windows node to that Jenkins installation. With labels applied to the node, I can control on which to build a project.

I also use EnvInject plugin on this Jenkins server, and (after many attempt to use script content) use a Groovy script to prepare the version number information to be used in the project being build, and in the Jenkins build flow to be able to track what version is built. For the later, I need to read a file storing the version number. While this worked when the host was the same as the slave (a Windows machine) this however doesn't work when the project is built on a different Windows slave.

Then I created a separate project to debug what is going on, and ended up with the following Groovy script:

```
def envVars = Thread.currentThread()?.executable.parent.builds[0].properties.get('envVars')
def line=""
def separator='/'
if (envVars['OS'] == 'Windows_NT') {
    separator = '\\'
}
// Where am I?
println new File(".").getCanonicalPath().toString()
new File(envVars['WORKSPACE'] + separator + 'Input.txt').withReader { line = it.readLine() }
return [
    SYSTEM: envVars['OS'],
    WS: envVars['WORKSPACE'] + separator + 'input.txt',
    TESTVAR: line,
]
```

And here's the output of this:

```
Started by user jadaml
[EnvInject] - Loading node environment variables.
Building remotely on Obsidian (Win32 Win32NT Win64 .NET WinNT Windows Win DotNet) in workspace D:\Jenkins\workspace\Rights Test
[EnvInject] - Executing scripts and injecting environment variables after the SCM step.
[EnvInject] - Evaluating the Groovy script content
/var/lib/jenkins
[EnvInject] - [ERROR] - Problems occurs on injecting env vars defined in the build wrapper: org.jenkinsci.lib.envinject.EnvInjectException: Failed to evaluate the script. java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\Jenkins\workspace\Rights Test\Input.txt (No such file or directory). See system log for more info
Finished: FAILURE
```

As you can see, the `println new File(".").getCanonicalPath().toString()` line printed `/var/lib/jenkins` indicating that the Gradle script is running on the host and not on the Windows slave.

At this point, it boils down to a problem that a project *maybe* building on a different machine where the Jenkins server is running and *may have to* read a remote file, unless it is running on the host.
How can I workaround this limitation?

---

I am read the [Jenkins java docs](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/overview-summary.html) and I feel I'm riding the roller coaster of "so close yet so far" ride.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After fumbling in the [Jenkins java docs](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/overview-summary.html) and searching on the internet, I have came to the conclusion that in my case, I need the [FilePath](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/FilePath.html) object, more precisely [this constructor](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/FilePath.html#FilePath-hudson.FilePath-java.lang.String-) to get a file object representing the remote file on the slave.

After I finally able to see the last piece I needed, I have searched and found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42018578/556048). This is my experimental script I ended up with:

```
import hudson.*
import jenkins.model.*

def envVars = Thread.currentThread()?.executable.parent.builds[0].properties.get('envVars')
def line=''
def separator='/'
// Needs to be tested if this works on 'master'
def channel = null

if (envVars['OS'] == 'Windows_NT') {
    separator = '\\'
}

if (envVars['NODE_NAME'] != 'master') {
    channel = Jenkins.instance.getComputer(envVars['NODE_NAME']).channel
}

def file = new FilePath(channel, envVars['WORKSPACE'] + separator + 'input.txt')

// Just read the first line
file.read().withReader { line = it.readLine() }

return [
    TESTVAR: line,
]
```

The `input.txt` file was created by hand in the workspace, and have a single line in it reading 'Wazup!' which could be read from the TESTVAR variable later on in the build job.

PS.:
Sorry for making a possible duplicate question but in the end I was so frustrated and couldn't even realize in the end what was I missing.

Another thing is that it seems that EnvInject's Groovy works slightly different from... wherever they are writing this Groovy script: Some of the variables are not available, like the `env` variable.