# Jenkins: File not found exception

Tags: file, jenkins, exception, groovy

I am trying to load a file from a repository I checked out. I am getting this error:

```
new File( iFilePath ) 

Err: Build failed with Error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Y:\Jenkins\workspace\TestBuilds\Matlab\m\Contents.m (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

This is explained because Jenkins try to look for the file on the master. While the file is actually located on the slave agent.

Any way to get around this ?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42018578/3486967

I don't think you can use the File class on anything but the Jenkins master; try using the [FilePath class](https://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/class-use/FilePath.html)